# Reporting across multiple CSV files

Tags: php, csv, reporting, data-processing

This might be a vague question. I am given 4 CSV files with about 500k row in each of them on a daily basis. I need to perform 'join' and 'where' equivalent RDMS operations on them to create daily reports. For example, the work flow could be:

1. Join 2 CSV files based on a column with IDs
2. Filter dataset down based on a date column
3. Join the new filtered dataset with another CSV file based on some where conditions
4. Further filter them down based on more criterias
5. .... // Repeat
6. Output final dataset into a CSV file

I was thinking of writing a PHP script to:

1. Load each CSV file into a relational database like MySQL
2. Perform the joins and where conditions with SQL
3. Load results into a temporary table
4. Repeat 2 and 3
5. Load final data into a table
6. Export the table into a CSV file.

What do you think is the best approach?

Comment: Why use MySQL and PHP?  You can do this with nothing more than `sh`, `join`, `sort`, and `awk`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell that's a great suggestion. I haven't done this kind of processing in shell scripts before. Can you do like datetime comparison, functions like AVG / SUM in shell as well?

Comment: HSQLDB supports Text Tables see (http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/texttables-chapt.html); you might be able to do a series of SQL statements ???